# IIS HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start event viewer showing Newtonsoft.Json could not be loaded

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis

I had this app running for over a year on an IIS server and suddenly after a deploy (after a year) the server started to fail with the following message:

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

I checked the logs under `Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application > .NET Runtime` and it says:

```
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 5.0.521.16609
.NET Version: 5.0.5
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   at SelectWiseAPI.Extensions.ObjectExtension.ToJsonIndented(Object obj)
   at SelectWiseAPI.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\selectwise-api\SelectWiseAPI\Startup.cs:line 40
...
```

I don't have any references to `13.0.0.0`, my packages are `13.0.1`.

Why is it trying to look for a different version? How can I fix this or find more information about it?

Comment: No, it's quite likely not trying to load a different version. The assembly version of the Newtonsoft.Json library does NOT include the minor version number of the release version. (It's related to how the author of Newtonsoft.Json decided to manage strong naming for the Newtonsoft.Json library. See https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1001 for confirmation by library author, but unfortunately no explanation as to why...)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace yeah, I copied and pasted my local machine DLL into the server and it solved all issues. For whatever reason it's resolving a different version on the server

Comment: .NET 5 is end of life, so anyway you need to upgrade to .NET 6 first. How did you publish this web app? Framework dependent or self contained?

Comment: The server has a script that pulls from git and runs `dotnet publish -c Release -o build`. So I guess the answer is that locally I have v6 but on the server v5 and that's what's causing the dependency to be different...